# Why isnt this function not returning f pd.DataFrames? Python

Tags: python, pandas, function

When I run this Code, load_data() will not return any of the data frames as pd.DataFrames. What am I doing wrong here? Thank you in advance for all your help!

```
def load_data():
    # Competency: reading files in Pandas, df manipulation, regex     
    scim_en = pd.read_excel('assets/scimagojr-3.xlsx')
    
    energy = pd.read_excel('assets/Energy Indicators.xls',na_values=["..."],header = None,skiprows=18,skipfooter= 38,usecols=[2,3,4,5],names=['Country', 'Energy Supply', 'Energy Supply per Capita', '% Renewable'])
    energy['Energy Supply'] = energy['Energy Supply']*1000000
    energy = energy.replace("Republic of Korea", "South Korea")
    energy = energy.replace("United States of America20", "United States")
    energy = energy.replace("United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland19", "United Kingdom")
    energy = energy.replace("China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region3", "Hong Kong")
    energy = energy.replace("China, Macao Special Administrative Region4", "Macao")
    energy["Country"] = energy["Country"].str.extract('(^[a-zA-Z\s]+)', expand=False).str.strip()
    
    gdp = pd.read_csv('assets/world_bank.csv', skiprows = 4)
    gdp = gdp.rename(columns = {'Country Name':'Country'})
    gdp = gdp.replace("Korea, Rep.", "South Korea")
    gdp = gdp.replace("Iran, Islamic Rep.", "Iran")
    gdp = gdp.replace("Hong Kong SAR, China", "Hong Kong")
    
    scim_en.set_index('Country')
    energy.set_index('Country')
    gdp.set_index('Country')
    
    return energy, gdp, scim_en
```

Comment: What types is it returning? Maybe check the types of energy, gdp, and scim_en after the calls to read_excel and read_csv to see if the bug is in I/O.

Comment: As far as I can tell it should. Unless maybe you're doing something like `data = load_data()`, in which case you'll get a tuple of DataFrames

Comment: `energy, gdp, scim_en = load_data()`
`print(energy) ?`

Comment: note the last 3 lines of your function isn't doing anything to the dataframes since `set_index` is not in inplace operation